# pandas grouby with many keys

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies in advance.  I'm new to Python / Pandas so this question is probably poorly posed.

I have a dataframe with about 4 million rows and roughly 10 columns.

I want to compute the mean of the first column (say A) for each group defined by the distinct values of each of the other columns (say B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J).  This defines about 200,000 groups.

I tried groupby, e.g.

```
mytest = df.groupby(['B','C','D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'])
mytest.mean()
```

This causes Python to grab all of the memory on the computer (32GB) and crash.  In Stata, I can obtain the desired result when I type:

```
collapse A, by(B C D E F G H I J)
```

which it does like a champ.

How would I go about the same operation using Pandas / Python?  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran this

```
df = pd.DataFrame((np.random.rand(4000000, 10) * 10).astype(int),
                   columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))

gb = df.groupby(list('BCDEFGHIJ'))

gb.mean()
```

with no issues.  I'm also on a 32-GB mem machine.  I've already been using a bunch of memory and this didn't have a big impact.  I'm guessing the issue is:

> This defines about 200,000 groups.

The only other thing I can think of is to restrict your groupby object to just the `['A']` column.  Like this:

```
gb = df.groupby(list('BCDEFGHIJ'))['A']
```

Otherwise, you'll have to write another algorithm... maybe.